# ldapsearch display objectClass content

Tags: ubuntu, ldap

With ldapsearch I get something like this:

```
#ldapsearch -x -b dc=my,dc=org uid=test -LLL

...
displayName: Some Name
uid: test
....
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
...
```

How do I display content of posixAccount for example?

Answer (score 1):

To return a specific attribute for a search-list, use the following syntax:

```
ldapsearch -x -b dc=ad,dc=example,dc=com '(&(uid=test))' posixAccount
```

Which will return the `posixAccount` attribute of any objects that have a "uid" value equal to "test".

Comment: I'm getting something like this:

    `# search result
    search: 2
    result: 0 Success

    # numResponses: 2
    # numEntries: 1`

Comment: @Redman I may have misunderstood what you were looking for. Try it with `'(&(objectClass=posixAccount))' uid` instead. Which will return the UID attribute of any object with an objectClass of posixAccount.